# Forward Akamai's True-Client-IP via F5 BigIP

Tags: cdn, f5-big-ip

Akamai returns client IP in True-Client-IP header. This can be disabled in Akamai settings so that Akamai will return client IP in HTTP-X-Forwarded-For header, but this will contain multiple IP addresses (Client IP, Proxy 1, Proxy 2, etc).

I need to retrieve the client IP in the web server (IIS 7.5), behind F5 load balancer.

What do I need to do in the F5?

Will F5 pass the True-Client-IP header to the web servers directly?

Or, should I change Akamai settings to return client ip in HTTP-X-Forwarded-For header instead?

Answer (score 1):

[Per StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33257139/forward-akamais-true-client-ip-via-f5-bigip/33264409#33264409):  I would use X-Forwarded-For because BIG-IP already has provisions to pass this through.

Depending on the version of BIG-IP, you can accomplish this in an iRule or in newer versions, X-Forwarded is a feature to enable within your HTTP profile. Then you just need to configure IIS to accept that new data.

https://devcentral.f5.com/questions/big-ip-http-profile-insert-x-forwarded-for-enabled

This should get you started. If you're pre 11.x TMOS, refer to this discussion:

https://devcentral.f5.com/questions/how-to-setup-x-forwarded-for-http-header-to-preserve-the-original-client-ip-address-for-traffic-translated-by-a-snat--25436

Hope this helps.

Comment: When you say "per StackOverflow...", it leads me to assume there was a similar question posted (and hopefully answered) there. Can you link to it for everyone's viewing pleasure?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add.

Comment: Apologies, for double question. I wanted to get opinion from both sys admins and developers on this matter. Since this has been redirected to Stackoverflow, I will follow up on Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

If the True-Client-IP header for whatever reason is not present or accurate, you might be able to pull the true client IP out of tcp options via an iRule as well. [Details here](https://devcentral.f5.com/articles/accessing-tcp-options-from-irules).